# Grunt is deleting my CSS files when I run it

Tags: html, css, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I used bower to install the 'font-awesome' css package. I then added the bower components path to my html as such:

```
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/animate.css/animate.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-duallistbox/src/bootstrap-duallistbox.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
```

When I run `grunt serve` the font-awesome stylesheet disappears!

I am doing an angular project that was scaffolded by yeoman.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution. That section of HTML is automatically populated by bower and grunt when the build runs. For whatever reason, font-awesome does not populate that area. Instead, I used components-font-awesome: `bower install components-font-awesome --save`